# Insert commas in a table/array

Tags: tables, arrays

I have a table, of the form

```
\documentclass[hyper,12pt,A4paper]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{cccc}
    ab=0 & cd=1 & efgh=-1 & pqr=30
\end{array} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

but of course, with many many more rows and columns. The output of this looks like this:

[image]

But instead, I would like to put commas between successive entries, to make it look something like this:

[image]

(with no comma after the last entry in a particular row). Of course, this is trivial to do by hand if there are only a few entries in the table. But I have about 50 such tables and each has a dimension of 5x5 or more. These tables were generated as output from some Mathematica code which is even harder to retrospectively modify.

So my question is: is there a way to modify the `\begin{array}{cccc}...\end{array}` to something which is schematically like `\begin{array}{c,c,c,c}...\end{array}` (which in this form is wrong -- I know!)?

Comment: why do you have an array here these are equations not matrices so the `array` layer is not needed (and makes it harder to get good output)

Comment: the answer to the question as asked is  `\begin{array}{c@{,}c@{,}c@{,}c}` but I suspect it is the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

A rather easy solution would be, to define your own separator, like `\def\sep{\unskip, &}` and using this in your tables instead of the `&` sign (the `\unskip` removes the spaces before the `,`). With this, you could just going once through all your tables and replace the `&` sign with your defined command.

Comment: it's all math mode so spaces are ignored anyway